# Windows 7, program MS Office 2003 Basic can't install because error says cant find PCHEALTH folder

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2003

Ok, I came home from work to find that my word and excel programs icons where changed ( I think it had a ? on the short cuts. When I clicked on the shortcuts an error message came up saying that could not access this program as it was moved, changed, or deleted. It also happened to  the programs Fire FOX, Thunderbird, System Mechanic, Malwarebytes, Winzip, Origin,steam and most games. I opened up esplower browser and something a window poped up downloading a program called System Health started to install. I closed down the browser (explorer). I unhooked my computer from the router and turned on the computer and ran Malwarebytes from thumb drive After I did a system restore there were only two listed. I go a lot of PuPS off like conduit and system health. Got the computer working again. I reinstalled Office Basic 2003 it worked, Later I tried to find word but was unable. I uninstalled office then tried to install office again but it stopped installing because it said can not fine PCHEALTH folder. I looked for the PCHEALTH folder in windows folder. Found it but it said access was denied. I ten ran CCleaner then I went back to the folder and it was gone.

How can replace the folder? Windows explore will not make me make a new folder. Can I go back to another system restore point to beable to go in and restore the PCHEALTH folder or do I have to do a clean reintall of windows 7. Don't want to to that but it looks like that is what I will have to do.

Comment: Sounds like a problem causes by malware.  I suggest you reinstall Windows 7 to remove all traces of the malware infection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Dude... I tried editing your post to make it less horrendous, but I can't even muddle my way through it. Sorry, I know English is not your primary language. Doesn't matter though. Your computer is infected with a virus.

Comment: I know its too long. It seems like I got rid of the virus, but the folder called "PCHEALTH" in the windows  folder is still missing. So, still unable to install MS Office 2003